# cannot import name Cop from keras.models python

Tags: python, python-2.7, theano, keras

Greeting Dear Community,

I try to use the python keras package and I got this error:
I am running this on a oracle-linux virtual box. Is it something to do 
it expects some kind of GPU box ?

Thx for the  help.

```
In [59]: from keras.models import Sequential#issue
    ...: 
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-59-0f55ca179bba>", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential#issue

  File "/home/oracle/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .utils.layer_utils import container_from_config

  File "/home/oracle/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/layer_utils.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ..layers.convolutional import Convolution1D, Convolution2D, MaxPooling1D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D

  File "/home/oracle/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 6, in <module>
    from theano.sandbox.cuda import dnn

  File "/home/oracle/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/dnn.py", line 9, in <module>
    from theano.gof import Optimizer, local_optimizer, COp

ImportError: cannot import name COp
```

The line from dnn.py

```
from theano.gof import Optimizer, local_optimizer, COp
```

Comment: Python is case sensitive, is it `Cop`?

Comment: Which version of Theano are you using?